Internal Service Error with Google Auth Popup
I am hosting my web app on Render, and when I try to call my Google authentication function this is the error:
File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 444, in run_local_server
    webbrowser.get(browser).open(auth_url, new=1, autoraise=True)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/webbrowser.py", line 66, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser

Locally, the google auth popup opens a new tab and users login as normal, but on Render I get an Internal Service Error

The webbrowser module is for using the browser installed on the device. There is usually no browser installed on a server.
